# Adding Multiple products to woo commerce cart through Ajax script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to add  multiple products in woo commerce through an ajax script that activates on button press.

Currently I have a php function that grabs all the product ids in a specific category depending on the page you're on. I want to be able to grab all of these ids and one by one add them to cart though an ajax script. The reason I'm doing this through ajax and not the typical /?addtocart=(multiple id's) is to stay on the same page and add an animation later on after the process has finished.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Comment: Can you show us some code? The PHP function and what you tried with ajax. Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.